# Re entry Ireland using IRP with close expiry date

Tags: visas, ireland, ryanair, visa-expiration, milan

I'm an Indonesian passport holder currently working in Ireland under Stamp 1. I am currently on a tour around Europe and will be flying back to Ireland from Milan via RyanAir on 10th November. My current Stamp 1 IRP card expires on 16th November. Will the RyanAir gives me trouble for having IRP card that is close to expiry date?

I also have a rubber stamp on the passport given by local Immigration Officer in Athlone that says I'm allowed to stay in Ireland until 1st January 2024, but I heard that's not a valid document for airlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TIMATIC states :

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to residents of Ireland (Rep.) must be valid on arrival.

As of the flight, the card is valid, and so is your permission to stay in Ireland

> Will the RyanAir gives me trouble for having IRP card that is close to expiry date?

With RyanAir... you never know how stubborn they can be sometimes, but having a valid RP should and will likely make the visa check go fine

Comment: When you say visa check, is that when I have to go their ticket desk and give them my passport/IRP card?

Comment: @Indokid Yes, this check

Comment: Ok thanks! I accept this as answer